# По какой причине в текстовой метки Label не отображается текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, tkinter, label

Есть 2 фрейма `One_line` и `Two_line` в первом размещена текстовая метка `Day` параметры которой определяются объектом класса `call_Text`, а во втором размещена текстовая метка `Month` параметры которой определяются внутри класса `Text` при вызове объекта класса `call_Text`, но ни в первом ни во втором случае текст не отображается, что странно, все остальное, цвет фона текстовой метки, размер, отображаются, что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title('Python')
root.geometry('605x80')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)


class Frames():
    List_frames = []
    def __init__(self, background_line, width_line, height_line):
        self.background_line = background_line
        self.width_line = width_line
        self.height_line = height_line 
        self.List_name_frames = ['One_line', 'Two_line']
        
        for name_line in self.List_name_frames:
            name_line = Frame(root, background = self.background_line, \
                              width = self.width_line, height = self.height_line)
            self.List_frames.append(name_line)
        
        for line in self.List_frames:
            line.pack(anchor = W)
            line.pack_propagate(False)
  
    
class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, font_text, bg_text, fg_text, width_texts, height_texts):
        self.Pixel_Virtual = tk.PhotoImage(width = 1)
        self.text = text
        self.bg_text = bg_text
        self.font_text = font_text
        self.fg_text = fg_text
        self.width_text = width_texts
        self.height_texts = height_texts
        
        Day = Label(Frames.List_frames[0], image = self.Pixel_Virtual, 
                    text = self.text, bg = self.bg_text, font = self.font_text,
                    fg = self.fg_text, width = self.width_text,
                    height = self.height_texts)
        Day.pack(side = LEFT) 
        
        Month = Label(Frames.List_frames[1], image = self.Pixel_Virtual, 
                    text = "Месяц", bg = 'aqua', font = 'Arial 14',
                    fg = 'black', width = 140, height = 40)
        Month.pack(side = LEFT)


call_Frames = Frames('olivedrab', 605, 40)

call_Text = Text("День", 'Arial 14', 'green', 'black', 140, 40) 


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: подскажите, для чего image = self.Pixel_Virtual для lable ?

Comment: @Интик  для того чтобы указывать ширину и высоту для label в пикселях

Comment: запустил ваш код.стёр чит и текст появился. попробуйте другой способ делать размеры, например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411225/tkinter-create-label-widget-containing-text-with-size-defined-by-pixel-dimen

Comment: @Интик Спасибо большое, помогло. Можете предположить по какой причине способ который использовал я, приводил к такому результату?

Comment: @Интик Понял принял, пасибо за инфу

Comment: @Интик, для этого для этого существует `compound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы `tkinter` отображал в `Label` или `Button` и текст и картинку то надо написать `compound` равный `'center'` | `'right'` | `'left'` | `'top'` | `'bottom'`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title('Python')
root.geometry('605x80')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)


class Frames():
    List_frames = []
    def __init__(self, background_line, width_line, height_line):
        self.background_line = background_line
        self.width_line = width_line
        self.height_line = height_line 
        self.List_name_frames = ['One_line', 'Two_line']
        
        for name_line in self.List_name_frames:
            name_line = Frame(root, background = self.background_line, \
                              width = self.width_line, height = self.height_line)
            self.List_frames.append(name_line)
        
        for line in self.List_frames:
            line.pack(anchor = W)
            line.pack_propagate(False)
  
    
class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, font_text, bg_text, fg_text, width_texts, height_texts):
        self.Pixel_Virtual = tk.PhotoImage(width = 1)
        self.text = text
        self.bg_text = bg_text
        self.font_text = font_text
        self.fg_text = fg_text
        self.width_text = width_texts
        self.height_texts = height_texts
        
        Day = Label(Frames.List_frames[0], image = self.Pixel_Virtual, 
                    text = self.text, bg = self.bg_text, font = self.font_text,
                    fg = self.fg_text, width = self.width_text,
                    height = self.height_texts, compound = 'center')
        Day.pack(side = LEFT) 
        
        Month = Label(Frames.List_frames[1], image = self.Pixel_Virtual, 
                    text = "Месяц", bg = 'aqua', font = 'Arial 14',
                    fg = 'black', width = 140, height = 40, compound='center')
        Month.pack(side = LEFT)


call_Frames = Frames('olivedrab', 605, 40)

call_Text = Text("День", 'Arial 14', 'green', 'black', 140, 40) 


root.mainloop()
```